# How to start homebrew Apache on boot?

Tags: homebrew, apache

I've switched out the default apache for the homebrew version. I've stopped the default apache starting on boot with:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

However, the homebrew version does not start automatically. The `httpd` process is running (as confirmed by `brew services start httpd`) but the server is not running, until I execute

```
sudo apachectl start
```

(`apachectl` here refers to the homebrew version at `/usr/local/bin/apachectl`)

I'm using macOS Mojave, and the homebrew Apache version is 2.4.37.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run:

```
brew services
```

The last two lines of the output gives the answer to your question:

```
If sudo is passed, operate on /Library/LaunchDaemons (started at boot).
Otherwise, operate on ~/Library/LaunchAgents (started at login).
```

So, to start apache at boot run:

```
sudo brew services start apache2
```

and to start apache at login run:

```
brew services start apache2
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried the accepted solution, but it didn't worked for me. The only way to get the autostart to work was by modifying the '.plist' file:

```
sudo brew services start apache2
sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
```

I added:

```
<string>/usr/local/bin/apachectl</string>
<string>start</string>
```

And I also commented out:

```
<string>/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd</string>
<string>-D</string>
<string>FOREGROUND</string>
```

The result looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.httpd</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/apachectl</string>
    <string>start</string>
    <!--
    <string>/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>FOREGROUND</string>
    -->
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Perfect. What this also solved for me was that httpd was always started under the wrong user, so after a reboot I'd have to kill it and then start it with the correct user.